# DensityPlot3D with transparent color for value of zero

Tags: plotting

I am trying to get the enclosed solid to plot with a nice clean density function but have gotten stuck.  Here is what I have so far.  Any ideas?

```
region = 0 <= z <= x^2 + y^2 && 
   0 <= x <= Sqrt[4 - y^2] && -Sqrt[4 - x^2] <= y <= Sqrt[4 - x^2];

solidRegion = 
 RegionPlot3D[region, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1, 5}, 
  PlotPoints -> 150, Mesh -> None]

fn[x_, y_, z_] = Piecewise[{{x^2 y, region}, {0, True}}];
DensityPlot3D[fn[x, y, z], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, .1, 5}, 
 ColorFunction -> "BrightBands", ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 10}}], Right], 
 PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like what Jose did but it doesn't actually get at what I want.  After some digging and help from a colleague here is the code that answers the mail.

```
region = 0 < z <= x^2 + y^2 && 
   0 <= x < Sqrt[4 - y^2] && -Sqrt[4 - x^2] < y < Sqrt[4 - x^2];
f[x_, y_, z_] = Piecewise[{{10 + x^2 y + z, region}, {0, True}}];
densityPlot = 
 DensityPlot3D[f[x, y, z], 
  Element[{x, y, z}, Cylinder[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 4}}, 2]],
  PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-1, 5}},
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
  PlotPoints -> 50,
  OpacityFunctionScaling -> False,
  PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 25}}], Right]]
```

[image: density plot]

The issue at hand appears to be that DensityPlot3D is restricted to primitive shapes (e.g., cylinder in this case).  So I restrict the domain within the primitive shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can delimitate the region of plotting by using `RegionFunction`. However, in your definition there is problem as you get complex values in your region because of the plotting range.

I try this by guessing what you want:

```
DensityPlot3D[x^2 y, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, .1, 5}, 
ColorFunction -> "BrightBands", ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
PlotLegends -> Placed[BarLegend[{Automatic, {0, 10}}], Right], 
PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> All, 
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 0 <= z <= x^2 + y^2 && 0 <= x <= 3 && -3 <= y <= 3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.  Not exactly what I was looking for but I finally figured it out.  See answer below.